# The Program gives garbage value for name[i], i= 1 to 3

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to programming. I was building a program to read in a single string, store it in different arrays and print them. But the output gives garbage values for `name[0]` and `name[1]` but the correct values for `name[2]` and `name[3]`. Any idea?

```
char buffer[80];
cin.getline(buffer, 80, '$');   
char* name[4];
name[0] = buffer;
int count = 0;  
for (char* p = buffer; *p != '\0'; p++)
    if (*p == '\n') {
        *p = '\0';  
        name[++count] = p+1;
    }
cout << " Your Enteries are :" << '\n'; 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << '\t' << i << ". [" << name[i] << "] " << endl;
```

Comment: What input are you testing it with?

Comment: *"But the output gives garbage values for name[0] and name[1] and correct value for name[2] and name[3]"*. You actually have garbage values in all members of name. You just got lucky (or unlucky) to see something reasonable in `name[2]` and `name[3]`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string` and `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: @DimChtz I guess he hasn't been taught that yet, and he's doing exercises with pointers for now

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing a *buffer overflow* for the array `name`.

Whan happens if you have (as I expect you do) 4 `\n` in your input? You execute the code inside the `if (*p == '\n')` branch 4 times. What is the value of the `++count` expression? The first time since `count` is initialised to `0`, `++count` evaluates to 1, the second time it evaluates to `2`, the third to `3`, the fourth to `4`. And what does that expression become when you substitute 4 to it?

```
name[4] = p+1;
```

So you're writing *outside* of the `name` array bounds, and destroy other variables in the stack in the process, in your case the start of the `buffer` array. If you are on a 64bit process you should expect 8 bytes of garbage at the beginning of `buffer`, which in your case happens to be where `name[0]` and `name[1]` point to.

This is always a risk when you're accepting input from user.
A solution in your case would be simply to bound check the arrays before accessing them:

```
for (char* p = buffer; *p != '\0'; p++)
    if (*p == '\n') {
        *p = '\0';
        if (++count < 4) {
            name[count] = p+1;
        }
    }
```